# How to return more detailed error when user cannot be validated

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am working on creating a custom membership class for my asp.net project. In the MembershipProvider class,  function for user validation is defined as follows.

```
public abstract bool ValidateUser(string username, string password);
```

The problem is validation can be failed for several reason, so I want to provide more detailed description as to why login failed (e.g., user is lockedout etc) but that cannnot be done via a bool return type. I certainly can create one of my method for validation as follows

```
public RichStatusDetailsEnum ValidateUser(string username, string password);
```

Problem with above is that I will not be able to call this method in a generic way (just by Membership.ValidateUser). Rather I will have to instantiate object of my custom membership provider etc etc. Does anyone else has encountered same issue and if there are any better ways of handling this type of situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Description

One way to get this done is

- Store the reason, why the validation failed, in the `HttpContext.Current.Items` Collection
- If `ValidateUser` failed, get the data and do something (like add an error to `ModelState.AddModelError("Property","Message");`

#### Sample

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{
    // your custom logic goes here
    HttpContext.Current.Items["ValidateUserResult"] = ValidateUserFailed.UserNameWasWrong;
    return false;
}

public enum ValidateUserFailed
{
    UserNameWasWrong, PasswordWasWrong, BecauseIDontLikeYou
}
```

your other class

#### More Information

- [MSDN - HttpContext.Items Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx)
- [MSDN - ViewDataDictionary.ModelState Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewdatadictionary.modelstate.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

As per [this MSDN resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx), the return will tell you if it is valid.  There are only two parameters (username and password).  If it is a `false` return, then you know one of them is off.  You can always test if the `UserName` is correct by calling [Membership.GetUser()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/40w5063z.aspx).  If the `MembershipUser` object returned is not null, then you know the `UserName` is correct.  In which case, that would lead you to believe that if `ValidateUser()` fails, it is a bad password.

**To see if the user is locked out**:  for the `MembershipUser` object that gets returned from `GetUser()`, you can test if the user is locked out by the property `Membershipuser.IsLockedOut`.

Comment: Let's say due to bad password attempts, user is locked out. Later user realized that he was using wrong password, so he attempts with a correct password. In this case username is valid, password is valid, but user should not be able to login due to lock-out. I would like to display a more user friendly message but that can only happen if I am getting detailed retun type (as if user couldn't login cuz password was bad or if he was locked out). I don't see how you can handle this with a bool return type

Comment: @palmsnow see my edit.  You can test the `MembershipUser` object from `GetUser()` for all types of user discrepancies.  You'll just have to get creative.

Comment: Thanks @Shark but I don't see any IsLockedOut property for Membership http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership_members(v=VS.90).aspx Am I looking at wrong class?

Comment: @palmsnow Yes, it's a property of the `MembershipUser` class.

Comment: That still doesn't cover all cases. For example: What if the user exists, but hasn't activated his account through double-opt-in yet?